# Use adb to read file

Tags: android, google-voice-search, adb

Is there a way to list all files inside an Android app? I want to access the file at the following URI:

```
content://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.AudioProvider/VoiceSearchOriginalAudioRecording3.amr
```

and its stored by my app with the package `com.example.db`.

I imagine there is something like adb content ... but how exactly can I do this? I can change the app permissions if needed.

Comment: is your app a debug or production version?

Comment: debug, but com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox is not. Any ides how to access these?

Comment: you need root to access internal storage for production version apps